# map an array inside react native functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to print My letters array on the screen and nothing is currently showing.

I've also tried to wrap the touchableOpacity view another View also or change it to View or Text only but I didn't succeeded yet.

```
const letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m'];

const OptionalLetters = props => {

    const mixedLetters = () => {

        letters.map(()=> (letter, key) => {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity key={Math.random()} onPress={()=> console.log('letter pressed')}>
                    <Text>{letter}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        })
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            {mixedLetters()}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: `Text` is a component ?. Please show the html of `Text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning the map. Do this:

```
const letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m'];

const OptionalLetters = props => {

    const mixedLetters = () => {

        return letters.map((letter, key) => {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity key={Math.random()} onPress={()=> console.log('letter pressed')}>
                    <Text>{letter}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        })
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            {mixedLetters()}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `() =>` in your code.

Change

```
letters.map(()=> (letter, key) => {
```

To

```
letters.map((letter, key) => {
```

You can also use the `key` (which holds the index so it's always unique) as the key

Comment: Haha yeah, that too!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot a return statement here `letters.map`